# C++ - How to create factory methods if class does not know about another class?

Tags: c++, factory

Let's say I have two base classes: A and B. They are both defined in different libraries. A knows about B but not the other way around.

Let's say I have some derived classes as well: C derives from A and D derives from B

I always create an object of type B first before creating an object of type A. So for example:

```
B *b = B::CreateB(some object); // static factory method that either creates either B or D.
...
A *a = A::CreateA(some object) // static factory method that either creates A or C
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to do this:

```
B *b = B::CreateB(some object); // static factory method that either creates either B or D.
...
A *a = b->CreateA() // dynamic factory method that either creates A or C based on the type of b.
```

The problem is that B is in a common library that does not know anything about the library A is in (and I don't want to change that).

What I would like to avoid is having to do the same work for determining what type to create two times. The "some object" that is passed into the methods is a complex object that I need to dig into in order to find out which type to create. It's not as simple as saying "if some object is this, create B, else create D". I know that I could have the base class store what type it is and use that info when creating A, but then that would defeat the purpose of having these class structures. Is there a cleaner way to create A based on what type B is?

Comment: If A and B should know to each other - they are tightly coupled and should be put into one library. I would rethink the design decision behind this, because perhaps neither A or B should know about each other - in such a case there should be a separate class that would act as a factory that ties together instances of A and B in some way.

Comment: Thats why factories commonly rely on polymorphism, any type which the factory instances inherits from a common interface

Comment: How about delegating the responsibility of interpreting "some object" to another class F? 

`F f(some object); A *a = f.createA(); B *b = f.createB();`

You can choose to interpret "some object" lazy and you can store whatever information you want in F.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answers everyone. After staring at the code for another 4 hours, I finally decided to just keep the code the way it is even if it's a little bit hokey and unclean in some ways. I did make a few optimizations (not related to this particular problem) and really in the end there is really only one case where a base class shouldn't know about a certain method (all types return NULL for the method except for the one type I'm interested in). Yes, it sucks, but ... I can live with that for now (and hopefully my coworkers will too). All of that work for this one thing, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe solution is to use [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

```
class B;
class D;
class BVisitor {
public:
   virtual void visit(B&);
   virtual void visit(D&);
};

class B {
public:
   virtual void accept(BVisitor& bVisitor) { bVisitor.visit(*this); }
};

class D: public B {
public:
   virtual void accept(BVisitor& bVisitor) { bVisitor.visit(*this); }
};
```

So, your `B/D` library does not know nothing about `A/c` classes.

Then use the real type information of `B` in this way:

```
class AFactory : public BVisitor {
public:
   A* getCreatedObject() { return a; }
   void visit(B& b) { a = new A(); }
   void visit(D& d) { a = new D(); }
private:
   A* a = nullptr;
};

A* A::createA(B& b) {
   AFactory af;
   b.accept(af);
   return af.getCreatedObject();  
}
```

This is just a scheme of solution. Pass in constructor of `AFactory` whatever extra-data you need.